# plotly / VS Code shows axes but does not show isosurface

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Simple (?) code, but nothing shows inside the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a three-dimensional grid of points.
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

# Calculate the distance from each point to the origin.
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

# Create an isosurface trace.
isosurface_trace = go.Isosurface(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    value=r,
    surface_count=10,
    opacity=0.5,
    isomin=0.1,
    isomax=0.5
)

# Create a figure and add the isosurface trace.
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(isosurface_trace)

# Add axes and a title.
fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(title="X"),
        yaxis=dict(title="Y"),
        zaxis=dict(title="Z"),
    ),
    title="Isosurface of a sphere",
)

# Display the figure.
fig.show()
```

[image: Output from VS Code Cell]

There are data points inside `r` that meet the iso-surface criteria:

```
np.any((r > 0.1) & (r < 0.5))
```

`True`

Is this:

- My bad `python` code?
- A problem rendering in `VS Code`?

Comment: Just updated `plotly`.  No change in results.

Comment: `r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)`. The xyz in it is an array containing 100 numbers. What exactly is the **r** you want to define?

Comment: well, I thought this would render a sphere

Comment: what I really want is to take a 3-D numpy array and render isosurfaces.  I get the same result as above... an empty X,Y,Z axis plot.  I am trying to simplify the problem until I understand how to do what I want

Comment: does it render outside of VS Code? Can you create a simpler plot to see if that works?

Comment: Same results with Spyder

Comment: Works fine with the exact same data in Matlab